# ELKI dbscan examples

Tags: cluster-analysis, dbscan, elki

I want to use dbscan algorithm in ELKI (not on GUI). Please give me some examples including loading data, running algorithm, displaying results? The docs of ELKI don't have any examples.

Answer (score 2):

Use the example at

https://elki-project.github.io/howto/java_api#PureJavaAPI

Rather than `KMeansLloyd`, you would use `DBSCAN`, of course.

This example does not set up an index, so the runtime will be O(n²). For larger data sets, indexes such as the cover tree give considerable performance benefits.

Setting up indexes etc. often is easier with the parameterization API.

Alternatively, you could use the parameterization API, as done in the unit test:

https://github.com/elki-project/elki/blob/master/elki-clustering/src/test/java/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/algorithm/clustering/DBSCANTest.java